# Does one have to Tovel the cup of Eliyahu?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada

Does one have to tovel their "kos shel Eliyahu". The reason I would say not is since one doesn't drink from it. However, many have the custom to pour the wine back into the bottle and make kiddush on it the following day so maybe it does need to be toiveled . Does anyone have a source which specifically discusses this?

Comment: If you like an answer, consider marking it correct :)

Answer (score 2):

This is addressed by R. Ziberstein in his Hashuqei Hemmed to Avodah Zarah (75b):

> קנה גביע מיוחד שישמש רק ל"כוס של אליהו" האם חייב טבילה
>   שאלה. אדם שקנה לפני הפסח גביע מיוחד לליל הסדר בתור "כוס של אליהו", גביע זה לא ישמש לשום דבר, ואף אדם בעולם לא ישתה ממנו, האם הוא חייב טבילה, כי אולי לא נחשב לכלי סעודה ופטור מטבילה?
>
> תשובה...כוס זה, שהוא מיוחד לכוסו של אליהו, ולא שותים בו, אולי אינו צריך טבילה, משום שאינו כלי סעודה
>
> אמנם יתכן שהכוס צריך טבילה, דלא גרע מכלים העשויים לקיום, דהיינו שלא שותים מכלים אלו, אלא שומרים בהם את היין, ואח"כ מוזגים את השתיה לכלי סעודה, דכתב הרע"א (בגליון השו"ע שם) דיש אומרים שצריכים טבילה, יעו"ש...ויעוין גם בבית יהודה (יו"ד סימן נב) שדן בדבר צלוחיות שלא שתו מהם באופן ישיר, אלא מזגו מהם לכלים אחרים, והעלה דלא בעי טבילה מכיון שהצלוחיות הוו ככלים העשויים לקיום, ולא לסעודה, יעו"ש.
>
> טעם נוסף יש להטביל את הכוס עכ"פ בלי ברכה, דלא גרע ממה שביאר בש"ך (שם ס"ק יא) את פסק הרמ"א שיש להטביל סכין שחיטה [בלי ברכה] אף על פי שאינו כלי סעודה, מפני שאפשר להשתמש בו לצורך מאכל. ואם כן ה"ה בעניננו, אפשר להשתמש בכוס זה גם לשימוש אחר.
>
> **ולמעשה נראה שיש להטביל כוס זה עם ברכה**, מאחר והרבה נוהגים, שיין זה שהיה בכוס של אליהו, משמש לקידוש ליום הפסח, דמכיון שנעשה ביין זה מצוה אחת, תיעשה בו מצוה נוספת של קידוש היום, ממילא נחשב הגביע לכלי סעודה, כי ממלאים בו יין לכוס של אליהו, ולמחרת שופכים ממנו לכוס של קידוש לשתיה, והגביע דומה לקדירה שמבשלים בו מאכל, ולא אוכלים ממנו אלא מוריקים אותו לצלחת וממנה אוכלים, בכל זאת הסיר נחשב כלי סעודה כי מבשלים בו את המזון אף על פי שאח"כ אוכלים אותו מתוך צלחת, כך גם בעניננו מוזגים יין לגביע של אליהו, ומתכננים שיין זה שנעשה בו מצוה תעשה בו מצוה אחרת, דומה הגביע לסיר הצריך טבילה.
>
> ויש להוסיף סברא נוספת שיתכן שלבסוף ישתמשו בכוס זה לשתיה, לכשימצא כוס יפה יותר, והרי כוס זה הוא כוס שראוי לשתיה. **לכן נראה שצריך להטבילו בברכה**.

He concludes that one should perform tevillah on it with the blessing.

Comment: that was fast...